# composer не устанавливается на компьютер

Tags: php, windows-7, composer

Скачал **ComposerSetup.exe** с официального сайта. Пробую установить и получаю следующую ошибку:

> Some settings on your machine may cause stability issues with Composer.
>   If you encounter issues, try to change the following:
>
> The Windows OneDrive folder is not supported on PHP versions below 7.2.23 and 7.3.10.
>   Upgrade your PHP (7.3.9) to use this location with Composer.

Не пойму в чем может быть проблема. Ведь на **windows 7** у меня нет никаких папок **onedrive**.

Ос: windows 7 максимальная
php: 7.3.9

Comment: а в PATH у вас прописана именно эта версия Php?

Comment: для локальной разработки рекомендую Laragon

Comment: @n.osennij да  проблема была именно в path, в пользовательской среде стояла версия 7.3 а в системной 7.1. Я не очень знаком с этими переменными поэтому не сразу дошло))

Answer (score 0):

Такая же проблема, требует php 7.2.22, а сайт требует php 7.3 (напр. у меня не работает ckeditor и т. д.). Работаю на Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 2019 v1809. Openserver 5.3.5. Композер не устанавливается, требует понижения php до 7.2.22.

В баг-трекере PHP [пишут следующее](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78220#1565374535):

> [2019-08-09 18:15 UTC] cmb@php.net
>
> Когда PHP запрашивает информацию о папке OneDrive, поле
> dataw.dwFileAttributes [ответа на запрос] равно 0x431, то есть "точка повторной обработки". Затем [из-за этого] PHP пытается открыть эту папку для получения деталей о "точке" и получает ошибку ERROR_NOT_A_REPARSE_POINT [("это не точка повторной обработки")].
>
> Это происходит только при работающем On-Demand. Если он отключен, папка [становится обычной и] перестаёт быть "точкой повторной обработки".

То есть надо отключить OneDrive Files On-Demand. Для этого надо:

1. Нажать на иконку OneDrive в панели уведомлений.
2. Выбрать "Справка и параметры -> Параметры".
3. Снять галочку "Экономьте место и скачивайте файлы по мере их использования".

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Лично у меня была проблема в том что я менял переменные среды пользователя а надо было менять системные.